# Curving a view like a book page

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

i need to curve a view to look like a bookpage sort of like this :

[image]

Anybody know if this is possible and how to do it ?

i've already read some questions on sort of the same matter here but never found a decent explanatory answer

Comment: There is a curve animation in UIView. Which animate like the map app and its from bottom. Is it possible to utilise that by rotate 90 and -90 degree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you can curving a view using opengl api.
You can read this [article](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/macosxdev/132053/), but it's on russian language.
[link for source code](http://hermes.lunaray.com/files/ConeCurl.zip).
[link for video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EKtQrPOX9ZA&feature=player_embedded);